# PCIe gen3 over a FMC connector

Tags: fpga, pcie

I am thinking to connect PCIe devices to my FPGA board via FMC connector (using a PCIe to FMC adapter).

Will I get full PCIe bandwidth for those devices on the FMC connector?
Not considering FPGA resources right now.

Comment: Much depends on the specific FMC connector and other interface wiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FMC uses Samtec [SEARAY connectors](https://www.samtec.com/products/seaf) which are rated for over 28Gbps, more than sufficient for PCIe Gen 3.

In fact many vendors are producing FPGA modules or carriers that run Gen 3 PCIe links through FMC connectors quite successfully.

The main thing to be sure of if designing your own board is to take care of how you route your differential pairs. Samtec provide final inch routing information to assist in that regard.